# Is it possible to keep input data after when it matched with spamming error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my case if user keeps submitting in a row, it will match with spamming alert.
This is working fine. But it refreshes all and all the fields become empty.
How can I avoid this?

**controller**

```
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @post = @user.comment_threads.last

    if @post
        last_time = @post.created_at
        if Time.now - last_time <= 10.second
            redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => @user.username
            flash[:notice] = "You cannot spam!"   
            return
        end
    end

    @user_who_commented = current_user
    @comment = Comment.build_from( @user, @user_who_commented.id, params[:users][:body] )
    @comment.comment_icon = params[:users][:comment_icon]
    @comment.save
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => @user.username
    flash[:notice] = "comment added!"
```

**view**

```
<%=form_for :users, url: url_for( :controller => :users, :action => :add_comment ) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :comment_icon %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move your spam control logic to model.

```
validate :spam_validation

 def spam_validation
   if !user_id.blank?
     post = user.comment_threads.last
     last_time = post.created_at
     if Time.now - last_time <= 10.second
       errors.add(:base, "You cannot spam!")
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that. But now I can spamming. It seems this validation is not working. Why?

Comment: in fact i didn't touch your validation code. Where did you put this validation, which model?

Comment: I just put that in the head of Comment model, which was created automatically by the gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'

Comment: def spam_validation errors.add(:base, "You cannot spam!") end  .Just try this if it is working change your error algorithm.

Comment: It's still the same. It seems validation is not working in this model. Why? because this is automatically created by the gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'??

Comment: Try validate :spam_validation, :on => :create

Comment: Thanks!! It's still the same. It shows "comment added" but it was not.

Comment: I guess your gem skips validation, it has its own validations.

Comment: yeah, probably. Is it still possible in the other way?